# Is there any reason so many people abbreviate "etcetera" as "ect."?

Tags: orthography, abbreviations, spelling-pronunciations

People do many strange things, such as spell "loose" (the opposite of tight) as "lose" (the opposite of win) - and even vice versa sometimes.

Another oddity is when they say "literally" when that is obviously not the case ("I literally died when I saw The Packers beat the Seahawks").

But one that I almost consider a crime against humanity (I'm easily riled at times) is when they abbreviate "etcetera" as "*ect.*"

What in the world are they saying in their mind when they write it that way -- "ek-tettera"? "ess-tettera"? Or what? Is there some method to their madness, or is this just one of those things I have to grin and bear?

Comment: Given how daft some parts of English spelling are, this peeve seems rather pointless. But to answer your question, yes, many people say /ek'setrə/. Whether they are the same people who write "ect." I don't know.

Comment: I say *"et cetera"* sometimes and I write 'e ***tc.*** '. Writing 'et cetera' seems to me to be a bit redundant. The reason for using the term is to get to the point of a topic quicker, so why not abbreviate it in the text? It has no importance there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a peeve.

Comment: I have no problem with abbrevating it as "etc."

Comment: @ColinFine: "this peeve seems rather pointless" Alas, most peeves are pointless.

Comment: It would be interesting if this were part of a larger phenomenon involving multisyllabic words in which the k sound is transposed with a contiguous consonant. I've noticed something similar with the surprisingly high frequency (in California, where I live) of "asterix" as a pronunciation of "asterisk." But the reality is that practically no one says "moqsuito" or "Pictairn Island."

Comment: @SvenYargs: Good point (nary a "moqsuito" is heard around hyar - I'm back in my native California, too, after years in Wisconsin, where the mosquito is or should be the state bird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are their editor, or otherwise in a *reasonable* position to correct them -- or unless they have requested feedback -- you're unlikely to be able to fix the problem. Grumble and move on.

(Personally, I think the best way to print this is to use the ligature: "&c." But the people who write "ect." would probably be completely baffled by this form.)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this spelling error comes from the speech patterns of people who are unaware of the spelling (and consequently the pronunciation) of the phrase in its full form. They think that they are hearing "ex cetera" or something along those lines. It is the result of the same error by which some people come to pronounce espresso as "expresso" . Such erroneous pronunciations are likely to crop up around foreign loanwords. This, I suppose, would constitute the method to the madness that you were wondering about.

Comment: Complicating matters is that it *is* "expreso" in Spanish, so exposure to that language/culture can embed the error. Spanish also allows double negatives, which are further spanners chucked into the works.